# Angular 6.x loading data to service from route resolver has no data in feature modules

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6.x app where my routes are lazy loaded. I created a resolver to add data to a service that contains data I need in all my feature modules. When I access my service from a component in my feature modules the data is not there. If I create a service in one of my feature modules and use the same resolver to add data to that service the data is available for that module. Not sure if this is the correct way to do this. I did not want to use ActivatedRouteSnapshot to retrieve my data. If you know what I am doing wrong or a better way to do this I would appreciate it.

Resolver

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppWideSettingsResolverService implements Resolve<any>{
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.appSettingsService.mode = appSettings.mode;
  }
  constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) { }
}
```

Service

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppWideSettingsService {
  mode: any;
  data: any;
  constructor() { }

  public isDev = (): boolean => {
    return this.mode === 'dev';
  }
}
```

Routes

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    data: {pageTitle: 'Home'},
    resolve: {
      data: AppWideSettingsResolverService
    },
    children: [
      {path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/+home/home.module#HomeModule',
      ...
```

Comment: Have you tried using config for application settings? I don't understand why u use service for app settings.

Comment: @EmreHIZLI Good point. I was making things harder than they should be.

Comment: Yes, i think so too. You can angular injection providers for app settings. like FeatureModule.forRoot(config).  you can work on this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using a service but rather used the settings file directly.